# Does the inequality $|S_n-1.99|<0.1$ hold for all values of $n$ greater than some $N\in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence

I am given the sequence $$S_n=\frac{2n+1}{n+3}$$ and asked to consider whether $1.99$ could be a possible limit. Intuition tells me that the limit is obviously $2$ and so I'm thinking that this should be impossible, however, am I wrong to evaluate as:
$$|S_n-1.99|=\left|\frac{2n+1}{n+3}-\frac{1.99n+5.97}{n+3}\right|<0.1$$
$$=\left|\frac{0.01n-4.97}{n+3}\right|<0.1 $$
From here we can find the two critical points when they are equal, which occur at $n=-58.55, 42.45$. Then doing a few calculations I found that $N=43$ is an element of $\mathbb N$ such that the inequality holds for all $n>N$.

This completely contradicts my thoughts going into the problem, however, so I am thinking I must have gone wrong somewhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Write $S_n=\frac {2n+6-5}{n+3}=\frac {2n+6}{n+3}-\frac 5{n+3}=2-\frac 5{n+3}$.  For large $n$ this is as close to $2$ as desired.  In particular, for $n>1000$ we have $|S_n-2|<.005$

Comment: Just because the inequlaity holds at $43$ you cannot conclude that it holds for $n >43$. If it holds for $n >43$ you would get $0,01 \leq 0,1$ when you lat $n \to \infty$ which is false. Your mistake is in the last step where you are jumping to a conclusion.

Comment: If the only times the inequality equals $0.1$ are those two instances and $n$ is less than $0.1$ at $43$ then it must be less than $0.1$ for all $n$ greater than it by continuity, no?

Comment: Keep in mind that the limit definition requires that this inequality hold no matter what the value of $\varepsilon$ is.  You can't, for example, just choose $\varepsilon = 0.1$, show that the difference is less than that beyond a given $N$, and therefore that's the limit. ¶ Your intuition that the limit is $2$ is correct; can you articulate that intuition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is true that
$$|S_n-1.99|\lt 0.1$$
for $n\gt42$. But we cannot say that
$$\forall\epsilon\gt0\quad\exists N:\forall n\gt N\quad|S_n-1.99|\lt \epsilon$$
For example take $\epsilon=0.005$ and we have that $\forall n\gt996$ the inequality is false. Hence one cannot say that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=1.99$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Note that we can rewrite $\;S_n=2-\dfrac 5{n+3}$, which shows $(S_n)$ is an *increasing* sequence which converges to $2$. Do, as $2-1.99 <0.1$, to ensure that $|S_n-1.99|<0.1$, it suffices to choose $n$ such that $$ S_n>1.99,\enspace\text{i.e. }\;\frac 5{n+3}<0.01.$$